# Possible ways for non-mandatory distribution of $b$ unique bottles and $p$ unique pens to $n$ unique students

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Assuming that $n$ students in a classroom have to be distributed $k$ unique bottles and $q$ unique pens, how many unique ways of doing that is possible?

$n \geq k$ and $n \geq q$

- A student may or may not get anything, since distribution is not mandatory.
- A student may get only a bottle.
- A student may get only a pen.
- A student may get both a bottle and a pen, but not more.

---

**Example-1**: {$ 1 $ student, $ 1 $ bottle, $ 1 $ pen} scenario gives four possibilities

1. $ (S_1, B_1, P_1) $
2. $ (S_1, B_1) $
3. $ (S_1, P_1) $
4. $ (S_1) $

---

**Example-2**: {$ 2 $ students, $ 1 $ bottle, $ 1 $ pen} scenario gives nine possibilities

1. $(S_1, B_1, P_1), (S_2)$
2. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2)$
3. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2)$
4. $(S_1), (S_2)$
5. $(S_1), (S_2, B_1, P_1)$
6. $(S_1), (S_2, B_1)$
7. $(S_1), (S_2, P_1)$
8. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2, P_1)$
9. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2, B_1)$

---

### **EDITED**

**Example-3**: {$ 2 $ students, $ 2 $ bottles, $ 2 $ pens} scenario gives 49 possibilities

1. $(S_1, B_1, P_1), (S_2, B_2, P_2)$
2. $(S_1, B_2), (S_2, B_1)$
3. $(S_1, B_1, P_1), (S_2, P_2)$
4. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2)$
5. $(S_1, B_2, P_2), (S_2, P_1)$
6. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2, B_2, P_2)$
7. $(S_1), (S_2, B_2, P_1)$
8. $(S_1, B_2), (S_2, B_1, P_1)$
9. $(S_1), (S_2, P_1)$
10. $(S_1, B_1, P_2), (S_2, B_2, P_1)$
11. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2, P_2)$
12. $(S_1, B_1, P_1), (S_2)$
13. $(S_1, B_2, P_1), (S_2, B_1)$
14. $(S_1, B_2, P_2), (S_2)$
15. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2, B_2, P_2)$
16. $(S_1), (S_2, B_2)$
17. $(S_1, P_2), (S_2, B_1, P_1)$
18. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2, B_2)$
19. $(S_1, P_2), (S_2, P_1)$
20. $(S_1, B_1, P_2), (S_2, B_2)$
21. $(S_1, B_2, P_1), (S_2, P_2)$
22. $(S_1, B_2), (S_2)$
23. $(S_1), (S_2, B_2, P_2)$
24. $(S_1, B_2), (S_2, B_1, P_2)$
25. $(S_1), (S_2, B_1, P_1)$
26. $(S_1, B_2, P_1), (S_2, B_1, P_2)$
27. $(S_1), (S_2)$
28. $(S_1, B_1, P_2), (S_2, P_1)$
29. $(S_1, B_2, P_1), (S_2)$
30. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2)$
31. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2, B_2, P_1)$
32. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2, B_1, P_2)$
33. $(S_1), (S_2, B_1)$
34. $(S_1, B_2, P_2), (S_2, B_1, P_1)$
35. $(S_1, B_1, P_1), (S_2, B_2)$
36. $(S_1, B_1, P_2), (S_2)$
37. $(S_1, B_2, P_2), (S_2, B_1)$
38. $(S_1, P_2), (S_2)$
39. $(S_1, P_2), (S_2, B_2, P_1)$
40. $(S_1), (S_2, B_1, P_2)$
41. $(S_1), (S_2, P_2)$
42. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2, B_1)$
43. $(S_1, P_1), (S_2, B_2)$
44. $(S_1, P_2), (S_2, B_1)$
45. $(S_1, P_2), (S_2, B_2)$
46. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2, P_1)$
47. $(S_1, B_1), (S_2, P_2)$
48. $(S_1, B_2), (S_2, P_1)$
49. $(S_1, B_2), (S_2, P_2)$

---

Comment: How many ways are there to distribute the bottles? How many ways are there to distribute the pens?  How many ways to one then the other?

Comment: https://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/probability-and-statistic/combinations-and-permutations

Comment: @saulspatz, each student can be given either zero bottle or just one unique bottle. Same is the case with the pen. I hope the examples are helpful.

Comment: I know how to do it.  The questions are intended as hints.  How many ways are there to choose which students get a bottle?

Comment: @saulspatz, okay, since $n \geq k$ and bottle is not mandatory, there $2^k$ ways for bottle possession. Similar is the case for pen.

Comment: Not quite.  That would be the case if $k=n$.  But suppose $k=1$  Then you can distribute no bottles in one way, or one bottle in $n$, so there are $n+1$ ways in all.

Comment: @saulspatz, are you saying there would be $n+1$ ways to distribute the bottles, no matter the value of $k$?

Comment: No.  I guess I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $b$ bottles are distributed, where $b$ can be any number from $0$ to $k$.
Since the bottles are distinguishable, there are $\binom kb$ ways to choose which bottles to distribute.

Since each student gets at most one bottle, there are $\binom nb$ to choose which students will get a bottle.  Finally, there are $b!$ ways to distribute the bottles to the students.

The total number of way to distribute the bottles is $$\sum_{b=0}^k\binom kb\binom nb b!$$

Similarly, the number to ways to distribute the pens is $$\sum_{p=0}^q\binom qp\binom np p!$$

By the multiplication principle, the number of ways to do both is $$\sum_{b=0}^k\binom kb\binom nb b!\sum_{p=0}^q\binom qp\binom np p!$$

When $k=q=n=2$ this gives $49$ ways.

**EDIT**

The number of ways of distributing the bottles is the number of ways to place any number from $0$ to $k$ non-attacking rooks on a $k\times n$ chessboard.  Think of the rows as students and the columns as bottles.  Whenever a rook is placed on the board, the student corresponding to the row gets the bottle corresponding to the column of the square the rook was placed on.  We can only have one rook in a row, so a student gets at most one bottle, and we can only have one rook in a column so that a bottle is given to a single student.

This turns out to be [A176120](http://oeis.org/A176120) in OEIS, where the formula I derived above is also given.

Similar remarks apply to the pens, of course.

Comment: Due to space limitation I couldn't add example-3 to the comment here. So, it has been added to the question.

Comment: That's good.  You should always add clarifying information to the question itself, not to the comments, according to the rules of the site.